# Tkinter moving a png on canvas using key press

Tags: python, tkinter, key, move

I have to create a little game as a schoolwork.
I'm trying to do a remake of a Zelda game using python and tkinter (tkinter is mandatory here).

Here is my problem, I can display the window, the walls and ground of the dungeon as well as the character, Link, but I can't find a way to make Link move using the keyboard.

Here is my complete code

```
#Imports
from tkinter import *


#Fonctions

def new_game():
    """Fonction qui lance le jeu, avec en premier le canvas de fond suivis du canvas de sol du dongeon"""
    fenetre.after(1, frame_wall)
    fenetre.after(2, canvas_donjon)



def canvas_donjon():
#Ici est le canvas de la pièce du donjon sur lequel s'affiche Link
    global link
    global dungeon_ground
    dungeon_ground = Canvas(fenetre, width=roomx, height=roomy, bg = 'green', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    dungeon_ground.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan= 14, columnspan=9)
    link = PhotoImage(file="LinksDown1.png")
    dungeon_ground.create_image(x,y, anchor=NW, image=link)



def menu_title():
    """Fonction lancant l'image du menu"""
    titreZelec = PhotoImage(file = ".\Image_Menu\TitreZelectromeca.png")
    canvas.create_image(menux/2, menuy/2, image = titreZelec)
    menu_title.grid(row = 0, column = 1)


def frame_wall():
    """Fonction plaçant l'image mur dans le premier canvas de fond"""
    mur_contour = PhotoImage(file = ".\Map\MurContours.png")
    canvas.create_image(wallx/2, wally/2, image = mur_contour)
    frame_wall.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

def presskey(event):
    global link
    global x
    global y
    if event.char == "q":
        dungeon_ground.move(link, -10, 0)
    elif event.char == "d":
        dungeon_ground.move(link, 10, 0)
    elif event.char == "z":
        dungeon_ground.move(link, 0, -10)
    elif event.char == "s":
        dungeon_ground.move(link, 0, 10) 


# Données

life_point = 3

black_cornerx = 213.5
black_cornery = 180.5

roomx = 660
roomy = 385

menux = 549
menuy = 413

wallx = 869
wally = 562

pathx = 55
pathy = 55

geox = 869
geoy = 650
geo = "%ix%i" % (geox,geoy)

persox = 255
persoy = 255

x = 40 #position de départ du perso
y = 40


#Création de la fenêtre

fenetre = Tk()
fenetre.config(background = 'black')
fenetre.geometry(geo)
fenetre.title('The legend of Zélectromécabilouschtroumpfos')
fenetre.iconbitmap(".\Images_Menu\Logo.ico")


# Création des boutons
demarrerJeu = Button(fenetre, text='Start adventure !', command = new_game)
quitterJeu = Button(fenetre, text='Quitter', command = fenetre.destroy)

label_test = Label(fenetre, text = "Life :" + life_point*"O")


# Création première grille
canvas = Canvas(fenetre, width=wallx, height=wally, bg = 'black', bd = 0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan= 2,columnspan=3)


#Placement dans la grille

demarrerJeu.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
quitterJeu.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
label_test.grid(row = 2, column =1)

fenetre.bind("<Key>", presskey)

# Afficher la fenêtre
fenetre.mainloop()
```

Here is the function creating the dungeon ground and the character

```
def canvas_donjon():
#Ici est le canvas de la pièce du donjon sur lequel s'affiche Link
    global link
    global dungeon_ground
    dungeon_ground = Canvas(fenetre, width=roomx, height=roomy, bg = 'green', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    dungeon_ground.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan= 14, columnspan=9)
    link = PhotoImage(file="LinksDown1.png")
    dungeon_ground.create_image(x,y, anchor=NW, image=link)
```

And here is the function managing the key press event

```
def presskey(event):
    global link
    global x
    global y
    if event.char == "q":
        dungeon_ground.move(link, -10, 0)
    elif event.char == "d":
        dungeon_ground.move(link, 10, 0)
    elif event.char == "z":
        dungeon_ground.move(link, 0, -10)
    elif event.char == "s":
        dungeon_ground.move(link, 0, 10)
```

I hope it's clear enough, I am new to python and Stackoverflow... I feel a bit overwhelmed.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had an epiphany this morning.

I think, the variable "link" is used to refer at the png file, which is different from the image object displayed on the canvas.
So, I created a new variable :

```
def canvas_donjon():
#Ici est le canvas de la pièce du donjon sur lequel s'affiche Link
    global link
    global img #added this line to be able to use the img variable elsewhere
    global dungeon_ground
    dungeon_ground = Canvas(fenetre, width=roomx, height=roomy, bg = 'green', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    dungeon_ground.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan= 14, columnspan=9)
    link = PhotoImage(file="LinksDown1.png")
    # img is the new variable
    img = dungeon_ground.create_image(x,y, anchor=NW, image=link)
```

This img variable refers to the image created on the canvas.
I used it in the presskey function :

```
def presskey(event):
    global img #here I replaced 'link' with 'img'
    global x
    global y
    if event.char == "q":
        dungeon_ground.move(img, -10, 0) #.move now uses img instead of link
    elif event.char == "d":
        dungeon_ground.move(img, 10, 0)
    elif event.char == "z":
        dungeon_ground.move(img, 0, -10)
    elif event.char == "s":
        dungeon_ground.move(img, 0, 10)
```

It works fine now ! I hope it'll help somebody else !

Cheers